# calling angular directive without element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a notification service in angular without having to add in a random element in the code. Most notifications repo's require an element be added into the code to call the directive:

```
HTML
<div notifications></div>

DIRECTIVE
myApp.directive('notifications', function() {});
```

It seems like the only reason this code exists is because a directive needs to be called. All the 'settings' can be handled in the provider when the notification is called:

```
$notify(settings)
```

#### Also, if it is possible to call the directive without the element, how can the directive create a 'notification' element at the bottom of the body, and bind itself to it?

So I ask, is it possible to call a directive without this arbitrary code? or is there an easier way to do this? or is this a stupid question?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: either I am confused or you are. I thought that directives are created using `angular.module.directive` method.

Comment: @akonsu - fixed the typo - I must be the confused one :)

Comment: ok. I still do not understand the question... How can a directive create an element and bind to it? what does this mean?

Comment: Right - that's my question: how can I create an element and bind to it with a directive? Angular is awesome, and directives are awesome - but in some cases it makes more sense to me to create the element with JS, rather than adding a lone element in the body. That would add an unnecessary extra step in the installation of the module, when JS is perfectly capable of adding it automagically.

With that in mind, I am perfectly aware how silly this question may seem - which is why I can be willing to except that this is not possible. Might as well ask and see, right?

Comment: when using angular, normally you do not create elements in javascript at all. angular does this. I am not sure if this is helpful...

Comment: If you create a DOM element outside of Angular it will live outside the Angular life cycle, To place it back into the Angular life cycle is more work than adding a single element to the DOM. The single element allows for code isolation of all code that manipulates the DOM and also indicates that notifications should be displayed on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend **against** using the code below, at least for common practice.
This notifications directive is an edge case where one and only one directive would ever be put on the page and it can live in an isolated scope off of the root scope as I would expect its data top be populated from services.

I am simply showing that what is being asked **is** possible.
Use of $compile should be avoided and there are better ways, such as requiring an element to be added to the DOM than this so that the element and the scope the notifications directive is bound to can be controlled.

```
module.directive('notification', 'blahBlahBlah');

module.run(function($document, $compile, $rootScope) {
    // create an isolated scope so that the notification directive does not have an option to pollute the root scope.
    var isolatedScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    var notificationDir = '<div notification></div>';
    var bodyElem = angular.element($document[0].body);
    bodyElem.append(notificationDir)
    $compile(notificationDir )(isolatedScope );
});
```

Comment: Why do you recommend against it? The code adds the element for you so you don't have to worry about it. It goes against angular "best practices", but I have a hard time believing that "best practices" when out in every case. If the element is only there to call the directive and contain the notifications, I see no reason why this is a bad idea :)

Comment: Requiring the directive to be on in the DOM gives the end user control. In this case it is not the end of the world, it does break the best practices but for global app notifications this is probably OK.

Comment: yes, if the user wanted to put the element somewhere else in the body (which defeats the point of 'global' notifications...), the element should be inserted manually. However like you said, best practices should not win out in every case - it's a simple war of simplicity for the user installing it, or simplicity in the code itself.